# Create computed column from another computed column, with constant literal

Tags: sql-server

```
create table factura (   
    importe money,
    unidades_vendidas int,
    subtotal as (unidades_vendidas * importe),
    total  as (subtotal * 1.18)  -- (1.18 needs to be a constant value)
)
```

How to define "total" to be as a 1.18 value of "subtotal"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like the error message says, you can't have a computed column based off another computed column. The way around that in your case would be to redo the calculation in the 2nd field.

```
create table factura (   
    importe money,
    unidades_vendidas int,
    subtotal as (unidades_vendidas * importe),
    total  as (unidades_vendidas * importe * 1.18) 
)
```

Alternatively you could use a trigger to populate that for you